# Which video game am I in?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

I have *a bunch of stories* to share I hope you won't find too *frightening* or *unbelievable* !
I played on a *mystical instrument* a *dark* and *mesmerizing* song. When it ended, I felt *sleepy*, *a bit angry*, and overall *sort of weird*.
Then a *desert witch* with *almost no clothes on* gave me a *light touch* with a *talisman*, and her *curse* made me *silent as well*.
My lips were *tighly shut* and I started *gasping for air*.
I began *looking for* some vehicle to *escape with*, and luckily I *encountered a* ...

**Which video game am I in? Bonus: What did I find ?**

---

Hints !

Hint 1 :

> The video game I'm looking for is a very famous one, which I'm confident everyone reading this has at the very least heard of.

Hint 2 :

> This is a **wordplay** puzzle, as mentionned by the tag. I've now explicitly indicated the important words.

Hint 3 :

> As suggested by generalcrispy in the comments, the key is to find synonyms to the emphasized words. All of these synonyms should lead you as a whole to the correct game (you don't need all of them to find the answer though).

Comment: Could we get another clue? Seeking synonyms for the emphasized words seems to be getting me nowhere.

Comment: and yet that is the right path. I'll edit it into a hint

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are in

> Pokemon (Red/Blue/Green)

1. **"Bunch of stories"**

   > Nine tales - Ninetales (38)  (Not available in Red, Gold or Crystal)
2. **"Frightening"**

   > Ghastly - Gastly (092)
3. **"Unbelievable"**

   > Far-fetched - Farfetch'd (083)
4. **"Mystical Instrument"**

   > Magic Harp - Magikarp (129) via @LeppyR64
5. **"Dark"**

   > Gloom (044) Not available in Blue/Green
6. **"Mesmerizing"**

   > Hypnotizing - Hypno  (097)
7. **"Sleepy"**

   > Drowsy -  Drowzee (096)
8. **"A Bit Angry"**

   > Crabby - Krabby (098)
9. **"Sort of Weird"**

   > Oddish (043)
10. **"Desert Witch"**

    > Sandshrew (027) (not on Red)
11. **"Almost no Clothes on"**

    > A bra - Abra (03) via @lostlemon
12. **"Light Touch"**

    > Slow poke - Slowpoke(079)
13. **"Talisman"**

    > Charm and her - Charmander (004) via @LeppyR64
14. **"Curse"**

    > Jinx (124)
15. **"Silent as well"**

    > Mute too - Mewtwo (150) via @LeppyR64
16. **"Tighly Shut"**

    > Sealed  - Seal(086)
17. **"Gasping for Air"**

    > Wheezing   - Weezing (110)
18. **"Looking For"**

    > Seeking - Seaking (119)
19. **"Escape With"**

    > Ride on - Rhydon (112) via @LeppyR64
20. **"Encountered a ?"**

    > Meet a Pod - Metapod (011) via @Annosz

Comment: Yes ! This is the right answer ! however, as a true trainer, I can only accept this answer if you catch'em all....

Comment: Still working on it!

Comment: To help you out a bit, the synonyms should (almost) match the actual names phonetically. So for example, in word 6, your second answer is correct. Also, Word 13 is a bit trickier than that.

Comment: All other guesses are good for the moment, except Word 4

Comment: Also, the last one (20) is part of the bonus (21) : you need to add a word to the synonym of 20 to get a name.

Comment: #15 -> (rot13)Ze Zvar

Comment: @Wondercricket I feel like the later part implies something else

Comment: @HenriqueValle Eh, worth a shot :) It was the only "silent" one I could think of

Comment: 11. Ekans?  Almost Naked.

Comment: 15. Mewtwo. Mute Too.

Comment: @LeppyR64 (Rot13) Fbygvhf fnvq vg vf cubargvpnyyl, fb ab nantenzf. Zrjgjb vfa'g ninvynoyr anghenyyl va Fvyire. Unless i'm wrong about that.

Comment: Yeah, and btw I'm not looking for a specific version of the game, don't wory about version exclusives. Let's admit trade is possible, and "Red/Blue/Yellow" is enough for an answer (we'll admit trade is possible) :)

Comment: So Generation 1, Kanto mons.

Comment: 4. Magic Harp - Magikarp (129)

Comment: So as mentionned earlier, Word 13 works slightly differently, as to get the character name, you need to read the text around the word also (without changing it).

Comment: 13. Charm and her - Charmander (004)

Comment: 19. Ride on - Rhydon (112)

Comment: 11. A Toque On - Dewgong (087) (Not confident with this one)

Comment: LeppyR64 : OK for everything except 11 (which is on the right tracks)

Comment: 20. Meet a pod - Metapod (011), so I guess you escaped with an escape pod. How fitting :)

Comment: For the last one missing, "A Toque on" was semantically pretty close (but phonetically worse) than the actual answer

Comment: I'd have imagined that since the clue for 20 was "encountered" instead of "encounter", the answer would just have been "met a pod" instead of "meet a pod", but it's the same result either way.

Comment: Nice! I had this thought with #7 but couldn't get the other synonyms worked out. Well done!

Comment: 11. Abra (063)? By wearing almost no clothes you'd see a bra?

Comment: Congratulations to everyone ! I provided an illustrated version of your answer in an answer below :)

Answer (score 7):

Would you be in...

> *The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask* ?

I have a bunch of stories to share I hope you won't find too frightening or unbelievable !
I played on a mystical instrument a dark and mesmerizing song.

> Did you play it on a guitar?

When it ended, I felt sleepy, a bit angry, and overall sort of weird.

> It's all right, that's normal when you're dead.

Then a desert witch with almost no clothes on gave me a light touch with a talisman, and her curse made me silent as well.

> She was probably a Gerudo, although I can't remember that part of the game specifically.

My lips were tighly shut and I started gasping for air.

> You became a mask, unable to move your face.

I began looking for some vehicle to escape with, and luckily I encountered a ...

> "Kokiri" kid on a horse, who ended up using your powers to enter the water dungeon?

Comment: I think this would probably be a correct answer... if I hadn't put the "wordplay" tag ;) I'll edit the question to make it more explicit.

Comment: My bad, I must've missed that.  This is the only thing that comes to mind, though, at least for the moment. -.-

Comment: This was also my line of thinking. I've no doubt the wordplay will lead elsewhere, but having jumped quite immediately to this answer it's hard for me to reframe my thinking to lead anywhere else.

Answer (score 5):

OP here. Answer has been found by Henrique Valle, with help from LeppyR64, Annosz and lostlemon. Here is a visual version of their answer !

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Could 11 - "Almost no Clothes on" be:

> Butt-er-free

?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this could be the case?

Comment: Well, if your butt is free you have almost no clothes on...

Comment: True, but you don't explain what your answer references - I assume it's related to Henrique's answer, but if so, this should be a comment on his answer, not a separate answer. Good thinking, though, in bringing up this possible solution piece.

Comment: This is not the answer to Word 11 (doesn't quite fit in the sentence), but boy now I wish it was.